# Want to apply the status for one case to all similar cases in data base using Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a fairly large data set(over a million rows) of patient encounters.  Each encounter(row) has a patient(column) and a primary stop code(column).  What I would like to do is when a patient has a specific stop code, label all of their other encounters with a status(new column) which can be used to pull that patient from the data set.

For example:

```
Patient             Stop Code              Status
John                 513                    Remove
John                 642                    
John                 125
```

Say stop code 513 is one which denotes all cases of John need to be removed from the data set.

A simple if then function can be used to assign the status for the case with actual 513 code, but I am stuck on how to designate "removal" status to the other cases in the data set.

Has anyone done something similar before?  Any advice you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you know what specific code you are looking for you can use COUNTIFS (into cell C2)

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A;A2;B:B;513)>0;"remove";"")
```

If you want to check for more than one code it is easier to use something like SUMPRODUCT search as COUNTIFS cant do OR operation

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A2)*((B:B=512)+(B:B=513)))>0;"remove";"")
```

Comment: Thank you, Pavel!  The IF Sumproduct formula works.  Like you suspected, with multiple stop codes the IF Countif was going to need an OR operator and that did not work.